# How do you find the most common day in a year in Google Sheets?

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, formula

I'm hard at work with [a Google Sheets spreadsheet of a huge catalog of wiki edits I made over the years](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jZCLwkmL6WobnE2JjHN3fE_S6QCz_ZnxKF3ssCrLYoI/edit?usp=sharing), and I'm having difficulties trying to find the most common day within a year. I've been able to check the most common day by checking with wikis and account, but I had no luck with going by year.

Here is the formula I developed to track most commonly edited day for a particular wiki:

`=IFERROR(INDEX('In one timezone (UTC)'!E:E,MODE(IF('In one timezone (UTC)'!A:A="Nookipedia", MATCH('In one timezone (UTC)'!E:E,'In one timezone (UTC)'!E:E,0)))),"None")`

And here was my attempt at trying to find the most commonly edited day of a particular year:

`=IFERROR(INDEX('In one timezone (UTC)'!E:E,MODE(IF(YEAR('In one timezone (UTC)'!E:E)="2012", MATCH('In one timezone (UTC)'!E:E,'In one timezone (UTC)'!E:E,0)))),"None")`

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORTN(QUERY({FILTER({B6:B, YEAR(B6:B)}, ISDATE_STRICT(B6:B))}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,count(Col1) 
  group by Col1,Col2,year(Col1) 
  order by Col2,count(Col1) 
  desc label count(Col1)''"), 9^9, 2, 2, 1), 9^9, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm...the formula is actually calling the dates on the "Other stats".

I'm sorry if I didn't clarify, the edits are in the "In one timezone (UTC)" sheet